# How do I programmatically find out the start date time (or uptime) of an Azure Cloud Service Role Instance?

Tags: azure

The old silverlight portal used to show the start datetime of each role instance so I could see when it last cycled.

As far as I can see this information is not surfaced in the `HTML5` portal.

Is there a way to programmatically access this information via `powershell` or the `REST API`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to see each role instance's uptime, but it looks like this will give you the time it's been since a service was last modified (i.e. with Swap VIPs, Uploading a Package, etc).  This and a good old fashioned ping (to make sure it's still alive) should help you know how long your services have been "stable".

```
[DateTime]::Now - (Get-AzureService | 
    Where-Object { $_.Label -eq 'MyService' } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DateModified)
```

Comment: I'm after more detail than DateModified.  Even if instances are frequently cycling, a service could be perceived as stable and within the Azure SLA if there are enough instances stood up to cover the instability.  I' dhave to watching the https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/CloudServicesExtension/CloudService/[serviceName]/instances portal or parse the infrastucture logs to find out.